# Prove error estimate of quadrature formula $\bigg|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx-f(x_\gamma)(b-a)\bigg|\le\frac{2\gamma^2-2\gamma+1}{2}||f'||_\infty (b-a)^2$

Tags: numerical-methods, quadrature

I've to show for

$$
f\in C^2[a,b], \qquad x_\gamma = a+\gamma(b-a), \qquad \gamma \in[0,1]
$$

that

$$
\bigg|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx - f(x_\gamma)(b-a)\bigg| \le \frac{2\gamma^2 - 2\gamma+1}{2} ||f'||_\infty (b-a)^2.
$$

So far I have:

\begin{align*}
\bigg| \int_a^b f(x)\,dx - f(x_\gamma)(b-a) \bigg|
    &= | f(\xi) * (b-a) - f(x_\gamma) * (b-a) |  && \xi \in (a, b) \\
    &= | f(\xi) - f(x_\gamma)| * (b-a)
\end{align*}

Therefore, I would have to show that
$$
|f(\xi) - f(x_\gamma)| \le \frac{1}{4} ||f'||_\infty(b-a)
$$

since $\frac{1}{4} \leqslant (\gamma-\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{2\gamma^2 - 2\gamma+1}{2}$.

Clearly $|f(\xi) - f(x_\gamma)|$ has to be less than $||f||_\infty(b-a)$ because that's the furthest $f(\xi)$ theoretically can "get away" from $f(x_\gamma)$ on that interval. But that does not explain the factor $\frac{1}{4}$.

Could you explain that to me?

*Additionally, every advice for a simpler proving method are welcome as well.*

Comment: Hint : Your expression is $\int_a^b (f(x)-f(x_{\gamma}))dx$; you have $|f(x)-f(x_{\gamma})|\leq \|f^{\prime}\||x-x_{\gamma}|$. Now integrate from $a$ to $x_{\gamma}$ and from $x_{\gamma}$ to $b$, and add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Kelenner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/159886/kelenner)'s hint I was able to solve it:

\begin{align*}
\bigg|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx - f(x_\gamma)(b-a)\bigg|
    &= \bigg| \int_a^b f(x) - f(x_\gamma) \,dx \bigg| \\
  &\le \int_a^b |f(x) - f(x_\gamma)| \,dx \\
  &\le \int_a^b ||f'||_\infty |x - x_\gamma| \,dx \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty \int_a^b |x-x_\gamma| \,dx \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \int_a^{x_\gamma} |x-x_\gamma| \,dx +
          \int_{x_\gamma}^b |x-x_\gamma| \,dx
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          - \int_a^{x_\gamma} x-x_\gamma \,dx +
          \int_{x_\gamma}^b x-x_\gamma \,dx
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \int_{x_\gamma}^b x-x_\gamma \,dx -
          \int_a^{x_\gamma} x-x_\gamma \,dx
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \int_{x_\gamma}^b x \,dx -\int_{x_\gamma}^bx_\gamma \,dx -
          \int_a^{x_\gamma} x \,dx + \int_a^{x_\gamma}x_\gamma \,dx
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{1}{2}b^2 - \frac{1}{2}\gamma^2 -
          (b-x_\gamma)x_\gamma -
          \frac{1}{2}\gamma^2 + \frac{1}{2}a^2 +
          (x_\gamma-a)x_\gamma
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{b^2+a^2}{2} - x_\gamma(b+a) + x_\gamma^2
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{b^2+a^2}{2} - (a+\gamma(b-a))(b+a) + (a+\gamma(b-a))^2
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{b^2+a^2}{2} - ab - a^2 -\gamma(b^2 - a^2) + a^2 + 2a\gamma(b-a) + \gamma^2(b-a)^2
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{b^2+a^2-2ab}{2} - \gamma(b^2 - a^2) + 2a\gamma(b-a) + \gamma^2(b-a)^2
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} - \gamma b^2 + \gamma a^2 + 2a\gamma b- 2\gamma a^2 + \gamma^2(b-a)^2
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} - \gamma (b^2 + a^2 - 2ab) + \gamma^2(b-a)^2
        \right) \\
    &= ||f'||_\infty
        \left(
          \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} - \gamma (b-a)^2 + \gamma^2(b-a)^2
        \right) \\
    &= \frac{2\gamma^2-2\gamma+1}{2}||f'||_\infty(b-a)^2
\end{align*}